# find a string with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the string `6c81748b9239e96e` it's random each time. Using the following code below. My problem is that it matches the entire string and I only need the random string that contains the letters and numbers.

String

```
<a href="playgame.aspx?gid=4&tag=6c81748b9239e96e">Play</a>
```

javascript regex

```
string.match(/\&tag\=[A-Za-z0-9]+\"\>/i);
```

Comment: What else than letters and numbers do you have in your string?

Comment: @Hauns TM i'm not understanding what you are asking? I added the full string

Comment: Just wrap [A-Za-z0-9]+ in round brackets - ([A-Za-z0-9]+)

Comment: The unedited question didn't show all the needed information!

Comment: @HaunsTM that's why it was edited :-) I didn't add anything actually, it was there, but hidden by SO's xss defense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Add the snippet provided by @Artem Barger to your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/851498 You need to slightly modify it, though (adding the `str` argument):

   ```
   function getParameterByName( name, str )
   {
       name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
       var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
       var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
       var results = regex.exec( str );
       if(results == null)
           return "";
       else
         return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
   }
   ```
2. Use it this way:

   ```
   var str = getParameterByName( 'tag', string );
   ```

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/u9MAv/

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expression Groups to match, and later access the pattern you are after. The regex you will need to use is like so: `/\&tag\=([A-Za-z0-9]+)\"\>/i`. The round brackets (`(` and `)`) will denote the group you want to capture. You can then access the capture group as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex).

EDIT: Upon closer inspection it seems that you might be using an incorrect regular expression. I am not really used to Javascript regexes but it seems that you are escaping the `&` and `=` and`>`, which is not required. Try this instead: `/&tag=([A-Za-z0-9]+)\">/i`.

Comment: @Mr.1.0: I think that you are using a wrong regular expression. I have tested a new one which seems to work. Please check my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myregexp = /(&tag=)([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b/img;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        // matched text: match[i]
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex

```
&tag=([A-Za-z\d]+)"
```

It's simplified (you escaped too much) and parenthesis were added to put the thing you want in group 1

In javascript this becomes

```
var myregexp = /&tag=([A-Za-z\d]+)"/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Explanation

```
Match the characters “&tag=” literally «&tag=»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([A-Za-z\d]+)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Za-z\d]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
      A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
      A single digit 0..9 «\d»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
```